# Powershell - Running remote session on intended server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

So I have a server set up for remoting called "Server01" so I can use the PS2 configuration.

Problem is I want to run the ISE as PS2 on the same machine.

So I am trying:

```
$username = "Domain\User"
$password = "Password"

$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password

$s=new-PSsession "Server01" -authentication Credssp -credential $cred -ConfigurationName PS2

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {

}
Remove-PSSession $s
```

while on "Server01" and I am getting an access denied error. I have made sure "Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials" is enabled and configured properly.

I am trying to avoid running this through the Management Shell because I would like to have a scheduled task kick off this script automatically.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're ultimately trying to do. Why was CredSSP necessary? How did you configure CredSSP? What's in the `PS2` configuration?

Comment: -credential for the Credssp. PS2 puts it in version 2. I am basically trying to run a remote session to the server that I am running the script from.

Comment: You can do that, even with CredSSP, so it seems like maybe your CredSSP configuration is incorrect, or your PS2 profile is not allowing the connecting user, so without seeing those things we can't tell. But, why are you doing this? For what purpose?

Comment: Because this has .net 4.0 and without using PS2 I cannot access SharePoint related items unless I use the management shell, which cannot be used in task manager so I cannot schedule it as a task. My credsp is correct because if I actually run it from another server it executes fine, I just cannot get it to execute using the same server acting as remote.

Comment: CredSSP defines which machines can be used as a client, and so does the configuration, so the fact that it works from another machine is more of a symptom of misconfiguration than proof that it's configured correctly. In any case, I think this is all unnecessary, see my forthcoming answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use session configurations to invoke PowerShell with version 2.0 in a scheduled task.

Just use:

```
powershell.exe -Version 2.0
```

In your task definition. This is way easier and safer than trying to remote into the local machine with CredSSP.